# Find the next term in the given sequence

Tags: sequence

I created this puzzle.
The sequence is as follows: $$320, 71,4632,1E3D, 84B7, 6154, 4F3A44, 38B12, 11F1, BE7E44$$

Find the next element in the above sequence.

Hint 1:

> What do Möbius strip and Klein bottle say?

Hint 2:

> It depends on how you look at it.

Hint 3:

> Ashcake, Ashtray, Ashplant, Ashcan, Ashman

Hint 4:

> $9(1,80)$

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether the letters are parts of the sequence terms, or whether e.g. they represent digits that you aren't telling us? (I assume the former, but I've seen other puzzles with sequences looking like this where it was the latter, hence the question.)

Comment: It is the former one @GarethMcCaughan